# Misinterpreted hours and minutes in Google Apps Script while reading Google Spreadsheet data

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-dates

I have a `datetime` columns in Google Spreadsheet which I'd like to iterate and use "hour" value to calculate something in custom Google Script. This is an example of a value I have in Spreadsheet:

[image]

My script looks like this:

```
function CALC_TEST() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("jan");
  var range = sheet.getRange("E3:F14");
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(values[i][1]);
  }  
}
```

If I take a look at my logs, the value is interpreted in a really strange way - as `Sat Dec 30 23:28:00 GMT+00:00 1899`

[image]

My Spreadsheet's timezone is set to `GMT+00:00` and I get the same result no matter if I try to parse the value with `getHours()` or `getUTCHours()` in my Script (obviously, since the value is already wrong before parsing :)).

Why is this happening? How is it possible that `22:00` becomes `23:28` all the sudden?

Comment: It's U.S. English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the timezone to a different one and then switching back fixed the problem. Might be related to [one](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2426) [of](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6680) [the](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/vjGrpW9PDr4) [bugs](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/XZkZim1ZwOM/VvAP47A5FQAJ) already [reported](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=timezone) to Google.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this by doing the following. I'm getting the time zone of the current sheet and the sheet that I'm copying from, changing the current one to match the source and then changing it back after copying. Seems to work great!

```
// Super annoying hack... Copying dates across time zones changes the timestamps and sometimes changes the dates so we're temporarily adjusting the time zone while we copy.

var DestTimeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

var SourceTimeZone = SourceSpreadSheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setSpreadsheetTimeZone( SourceTimeZone );

// Overwrite data

Sheet.clearContents();
Sheet.getRange(1,1,SourceRows,SourceColumns).setValues(SourceData);

// Reset the timezone.

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setSpreadsheetTimeZone( DestTimeZone );
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The script is incomplete.... several variable declarations are missing and the function statement is missing too.

Comment: Peter, could you please update your answer?